# preferred glyph fallback font

Tags: text-rendering, glyph, fontconfig

[Problem] When rendering a string of multiple languages, the font selected might not support all glyphs.  Is it possible to specify a list of fonts to test the glyph through?

[Context] The system is Pango + Fontconfig, my first guess this is something to address at fontconfig level.  However from fontconfig [spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html), I don't see something directly relevant.

[Questions]

1. Is this something to be addressed at fontconfig level?
2. I tried to add the below in **/etc/fonts/local.conf**, and then use "**fc-match "FreightSans Pro" -s**" to test.  It seems working because of seeing Noto fonts right after FreigSanPro.  However, the rendering system with Pango doesn't seem to use Noto fonts.  What could be the reason?

> ```
> <alias>
>     <family>FreightSans Pro</family> 
>     <prefer>
>         <family>Noto Sans</family>
>         <family>Noto Emoji</family>
>         <family>Noto Sans Armenian</family>
>         <family>Noto Sans Avestan</family>
>         <family>Noto Sans Balinese</family>
>         <family>Noto Sans Bamum</family>
>         ......
>     </prefer>
> </alias>
> ```

Thanks for any thought. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got it working.  It looks the build of fontconfig I have isn't looking /etc/fonts/ for config files.  Therefore by adding the environment variable below the system is picking up my customized conf file and work as expected.

```
export FONTCONFIG_PATH=/etc/fonts/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. fontconfig manages fallback on Linux.
2. I doubt you should provide overrides for an exclusive family. Try general names like `sans`, `sans-serif` or `monospace`.

Comment: Thanks Tatsuyuki!!   I tried them too, and no luck. :(   I'm wondering if this has something to do with Pango.  What does Pango do so local.conf doesn't take effects?  I doubt that because Pango shouldn't overwrite system level behavior config, right?